# Google Maps marking

Tags: google-maps

How do I mark a company on Google Maps, so it could be added to contact page via iframe?

Comment: What exactly do you want to display on your website? A map with a marker or what?

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Static Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/simplewizard/makestaticmap.html) makes it easy to mark a location in a map & embed it in a web page. [Google Static Maps API accepts inputs to generate a map through querystring values.](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2010/03/display-region-route-or-location-with.html)

[Google's Driving Directions gadget](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/gadgets/directions/) shows a map & also provides driving directions based on    the address of your company's location that you can preset & the starting point specified dynamically by a customer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to go over the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/).

You'll probably use a [simple info window](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple.html) or [simple marker](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple.html) ([more examples](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html)).

This question may be better suited for Stack Overflow if you need help with the code.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to add your company to Google Local through the Google Places interface http://google.com/places This way people will find it not only graphically through a user-defined placemark (which is actually what you were asking about, but really not what you want to do!) but also by searching Google.

See also Google Places for Business http://places.google.com/business

Answer (score 0):

And once it is added, you may use the embed code to add it to your website. You don't necessarily need to add it to places to have a marker and map added to your site (but I agree with msanford that's what you should do). Simply, you can search [address (business_name)] add then use the embed code for that result.